# Non-existent Excel Worksheet, but Formulas and Defined names still work?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file that is referencing a non-existent worksheet. But the formulas and stuff still work just like nothing is broken (no "#REF" appear). How is this possible?

E.g. Worksheet A! has a VLOOKUP formula referencing a Defined Name in Worksheet B! which is a table range. Except Worksheet B! is nowhere to be found. Yet, the formula still works even as other variables in the formula are updated.

Some additional info:

1) All workbook / worksheet / macros are unprotected

2) There are no hidden worksheets

3) When you open the VBA editor, under MS Excel Objects, the other "ghost" worksheets appear. If you right click on them, you can "View Code". But "View object" option is blanked out. But there are no VBA code for these "ghost" worksheets

4) When you open name manager, the defined names still show Worksheet B! as if it was still there and nothing was wrong.

Anyone knows how this happened?

Comment: What's the status when you go in Data/Connections/Edit Links?

Comment: `There are no hidden worksheets`, but maybe there are [xlSheetVeryHidden](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142530/en) worksheets? Try to evaluate following code: `For Each w In Worksheets: w.Visible = xlSheetVisible: Next`

Comment: Thank you Simoco. That totally worked! :)