# Find worksheet name mapping in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have inherited an Excel workbook with several worksheets, all with named tabs.  I have some VBA code that runs depending on buttons and inputs.  When I compare the VBAProject and the list of Excel Objects, the sheet's names match the tabs.  All good so far.

However, within the VBA code and on the spreadsheets itself, it refers to other worksheets.  They are still part of the workbook, and I think that the code was created, and then tabs were renamed.  But I don't know how Excel keeps the connection, or, more importantly, how I am supposed to figure out the connections.

So, for instance, I have a VLOOKUP that refers to MiscDataRange

```
=IF((VLOOKUP(E4,MiscDataRange,4,0))="Y"...
```

I don't know what MiscDataRange is, but within the VBA code I find one reference.  Right after specifying worksheet "Misc Interrupt", which is NOT any of the named tabs.

```
    Worksheets("Misc Interrupt").Range("H2:H47") = "N" 'Reset to N at noon.

    UpdateData

    Range("MiscDataRange").ClearContents
```

I do have a sheet called MiscInt, and it appears to be the sheet that "Misc Interrupt" is using and MiscDataRange is referencing.

My problem is there is a hole in my knowledge - I can guess that MiscInt and Misc Interrupt are the same worksheet, that the VLookup is referring to data on the MiscInt sheet.  But I am reduced to guessing.  I cannot find anything in the file that maps those two as the same.  Where would I look to find that?

This question seems related, except he simply has a VLookup, and isn't looking at the VBA code: [Non-existent Excel Worksheet, but Formulas and Defined names still work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333516/non-existent-excel-worksheet-but-formulas-and-defined-names-still-work).  In addition, from the VBA code, I can see hidden and visible worksheets.

Comment: `Range("MiscDataRange").ClearContents` does not reference any particular sheet. it will use any sheet that is active at the moment the code executes.

Comment: what happens if you execute `Range("MiscDataRange").ClearContents` or `Range("MiscDataRange").Select` ?

Comment: unhide all the worksheets

Comment: You can find exactly where Named ranges are from Immediate Window, e.g. `Range("MiscDataRange").Address(External:=True)`

Comment: You can also find out where Named Ranges refer to by going to `Formulas / Name Manager` on the Excel menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the Names manager by going to the Formula Tab and clicking **Names Manager** or pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or you can paste a list of Names and what the names reference by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>.  It may be necessary to unhide the names first.

[image]

```
Sub ShowAllNames()
    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        n.Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one! **`F3`** then **Paste List** is something i didn't know! I wrote macro to extract same details when I had to troubleshoot a template with macro that has over 1000 named ranges (many are duplicates). Only drawback is not showing **Table** names and their range.

Comment: Thanks! Your `Range("MiscDataRange").Address(External:=True)` comment was spot on.

Comment: I see the Formulas name manager (mine has a lot of #REFs in it!), and have made the sub and run it.  But I'm not quite sure what you're clicking on that shows the results of the sub.  If it's the same as the name manager, then I guess I don't need that.

Comment: `F3` will bring up the paste name box.

Comment: Interestingly, the formula name manager brings up 9 names, I have 11 sheets, and there are no names that match a sheet name.  It does tell me that my MiscDataRange is range on MiscInt.  I'm guessing it only lists names that are in addition to straightforward sheet names?

Comment: The Names Manager has a FIlter button that will allow you to change it's scope

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you're looking to find where those named ranges are.

You can use a sub like this:

```
Sub t()
Debug.Print "Sheet: " & Range("testNamedRange").Parent.Name
Debug.Print "Full Location: " & Range("testnamedrange").Name
Debug.Print "File path: " & Range("testnamedrange").Worksheet.Parent.Path
End Sub
```

Does that help?